# having this error TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects when trying to do math with variables stored with pickle

Tags: python, python-2.7, integer, pickle

I'm having this error

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

when I'm trying to do calculations with variables sent using pickle from my client file to my server when a second computer joins my server heres my code for my server

```
import socket, select, pickle
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(('', 4000))
server.listen(5)
pjoin = 0

clients = []
while True:
    Connections, wlist, xlist = select.select([server], [], [], 0.05)

    for Connection in Connections:
        client, Informations = Connection.accept()
        clients.append(client)

        clientsList = []
    try:
        clientsList, wlist, xlist = select.select(clients, [], [], 0.05)
    except select.error:
        pass
    else:
        for clientInList in clientsList:
            join = clientInList.recv(1024)
            join = pickle.loads(join)
            print(join)
            pjoin += (join)
            pjoin = pickle.dumps(pjoin)
            clientInList.send(pjoin)

clientInList.close()
server.close()
```

I have it so when a client joins it sends the variable `join` which has the value to the server and then the server adds that to `pjoin` and sends that back. That way when a second computer using the same client file joins the same server it ends up sending 2 to the second computer and that way the client file can know if its the first to join the server or the second and so on.

But this isn't working for me the server keeps feeding me the error above.

Comment: We don't need all this code. Just the line where it's occurring with a little context and the full stack trace would be nice. As it is, the error is telling you exactly what is wrong: You're trying to add a string (str) and a number (int). Python will not do that without an explicit conversion one way or the other.

Answer (score 1):

You replaced the `pjoin` *integer* with a string:

```
# at the top
pjoin = 0

# inside the while True and for clientInList loops
pjoin = pickle.dumps(pjoin)
```

`pickle.dumps()` returns a string object. Next time you get a response from a client, you'll now will sum an integer to a string:

```
pjoin += (join)
```

It looks to me you can remedy this by not re-using `pjoin` for the `pickle.dumps()` result:

```
for clientInList in clientsList:
    join = clientInList.recv(1024)
    join = pickle.loads(join)
    print(join)
    pjoin += (join)
    response = pickle.dumps(pjoin)
    clientInList.send(response)
```